# Does anyone know how Android detects the presence of internet access over wifi?

Tags: networking

I'm working on a "spoof internet" for an art installation, and I've run into a snag that you might be able to help me with. The goal is to create a wireless hotspot that looks like it has internet access, but resolves all domains to the address of my laptop. From there, I'm hosting satirical versions of popular websites.

The problem is that mobile devices (I've only tested on Android so far, but I assume iOS does this as well) can detect the lack of internet access on a wifi hotspot and will fall back to their cell radio. I was hoping that it was simply "calling home" and that I could fake a response, but I don't see any traffic of that sort when monitoring the network with wireshark.

Does anyone have any insight into how this is done?

Comment: Seems really simple to test and figure it out for yourself.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I don't see any relevant traffic in Wireshark. I'm not super knowledgeable about networking, so if there's an avenue of investigation I'm missing, I'd appreciate pointers.

Comment: You're on the right track. Perform a packet capture on the router that the network traffic passes through. If any packets are sent by the device, you'll see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for [Apple iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_md.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-ReadMe_md-DontLinkElementID_11)

for [Chromium OS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24132800/2782736)

spoof both of those domains through a local DNS under your control on that LAN (which based on your question, I am guessing you know how to achieve, hint: [powerdns](https://www.powerdns.com/downloads.html))

and serve the necessary URLs so that the phones get the content or HTTP code that they are expecting

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. You're awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael The linked answer is incomplete. The Android version running on my phone will also communicate with my Gmail account and use two different colors for the WiFi icon depending on whether it succeeded or not.

Comment: @kasperd indeed, but that check won't disable the wifi to fallback to mobile internet, plus it depends on the condition that the user is using a gmail account and it has enabled frequent checks. If you want to avoid that, you would need to spoof the user's gmail authentication which is potentially illegal in several jurisdictions.

Comment: @Michael please add a comment after you have accomplished your goal in order to have full feedback on this

Comment: @kamihack If you actually find a way to MITM the communication between Android and Gmail, don't abuse it. Instead sign up for Google's bug bounty program and try to claim a price for the method you found. If you want to give users the impression they have access to a fully functional internet connection, then create a whitelist of IPs that Android need https access to and allow communication to go through to those IPs on port 443 without any hijacking attempt whatsoever. No MITM needed.

Comment: @kasperd proxying gmail on ports 80 & 443 is the way to handle that. My main point is that Android checking gmail account doesn't trump the main purpose.

Comment: Connectivity spoofing is working for Android, though I found that the URL requested was actually http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204 rather than http://clients3.google.com/generate_204. It's possible that this is dependant on Android version. I'm supporting both, just in case.

Comment: Connectivity spoofing is now also working in iOS. The URL that needs to be replicated is http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html, and it needs to respond with a 200 and exactly the following content: "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML>"

Comment: @Michael thank you, this helps the whole community